# npm errors while trying to run json scripts on new laptop

Tags: node.js, npm

I did an online course about coding, which included a couple of small scripts to compile my sass and concat my CSS files. Recently I got a new laptop and I did install node, and installed my dependencies but for some reason I can't get any of them to work.

Here is what I did:

1. Installed node (current version: `v10.15.2`)
2. Run the following commands:

   1. `npm install`
   2. `sudo npm install live-server -g`
   3. `npm install autoprefixer --save-dev`
   4. `npm install postcss-cli --save-dev`

Here are my JSON scripts:

```
"scripts": {
    "watch:sass": "node-sass sass/main.scss css/style.css -w",
    "devserver": "live-server",
    "start": "npm-run-all --parallel devserver watch:sass",
    "compile:sass": "node-sass sass/main.scss css/style.comp.css",
    "concat:css": "concat -o css/style.concat.css css/icon-font.css css/style.comp.css",
    "prefix:css": "postcss --use autoprefixer -b 'last 10 versions' css/style.concat.css -o css/style.prefix.css",
    "compress:css": "node-sass css/style.prefix.css css/style.css --output-style compressed",
    "build:css": "npm-run-all compile:sass concat:css prefix:css compress:css"
  },
```

The errors I got:

> ```
>  npm start
>
>  talentsfestivals@1.0.0 start /Users/vasil.krumov/Documents/Projects/TalentsFestivals
>  npm-run-all --parallel devserver watch:sass
>
> internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:583
>     throw err;
>     ^
>
> Error: Cannot find module '../common/bootstrap'
>     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:581:15)
>     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:507:25)
>     at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
>     at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
>     at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/vasil.krumov/Documents/Projects/TalentsFestivals/node_modules/.bin/npm-run-all:13:1)
>     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
>     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
>     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
>     at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
>     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
> npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
> npm ERR! errno 1
> npm ERR! talentsfestivals@1.0.0 start: `npm-run-all --parallel devserver watch:sass`
> npm ERR! Exit status 1
> npm ERR!
> npm ERR! Failed at the talentsfestivals@1.0.0 start script.
> npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
> npm ERR!     /Users/vasil.krumov/.npm/_logs/2019-03-03T15_29_19_750Z-debug.log
> ```

Can anyone please help me?

Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: Seems like it can't find bootstrap. `Cannot find module '../common/bootstrap'`

Comment: I am not using bootstrap on this site at all :( I did a bootstrap exercise earlier, but I am not working on that project, it is a completely different one.

Comment: could you try to do the following in terminal:
`rm -rf node_modules`

`npm install`
provide the contents of that error message

Comment: rm -rf node_modules npm install
npm install

> fsevents@1.2.7 install /Users/vasil.krumov/Documents/Projects/TalentsFestivals/node_modules/fsevents
> node install

Comment: node-pre-gyp WARN Using needle for node-pre-gyp https download 
[fsevents] Success: "/Users/vasil.krumov/Documents/Projects/TalentsFestivals/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v64-darwin-x64/fse.node" is installed via remote

> nodemon@1.18.10 postinstall /Users/vasil.krumov/Documents/Projects/TalentsFestivals/node_modules/nodemon
> node bin/postinstall || exit 0

npm WARN talentsfestivals@1.0.0 No repository field.

added 455 packages from 214 contributors and audited 5520 packages in 7.173s
found 0 vulnerabilities

Comment: And it still gives you the same error message when you try to run npm again?

Comment: This is what I get this time around:

https://imgur.com/a/GNhn8Vx

Comment: Its saying node-sass is missing, try `npm install -g node-sass`

Comment: I did, went through mostly at the end I Get those errors:

https://imgur.com/a/ZqP161P

Comment: Well aren't you the lucky one, some people would just have you sudo install the package, but that is not good practice, you probably need to do some cleaning and install npm again with a node version manager. [documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/resolving-eacces-permissions-errors-when-installing-packages-globally)

Comment: That is the result of me installing it sudo in front, still got those errors. Let me check the documentation. Thank you for the help thus far! I really appreciate it.

Comment: I did reinstall npm and still run into the errors on the screenshot above, my desperation is real :(

Comment: After everything I run a couple of other commands, reinstalled each line and for some reason it worked!!!!! THANK YOU!

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of others searching for the solution to your problem, i will write it here to make it easier to locate. 
The first problem seemed to be some old modules, to clean it up remove you modules folder and npm install again.
The next problem seemed to be EACCES permissions errors. Usually you don't want to sudo install npm packages. If you have EACCES permissions errors look at this [documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/resolving-eacces-permissions-errors-when-installing-packages-globally)